iOS prev/next button becomes disabled when next input field is outside of view
Classic use case: Using Cordova to build hybrid apps.
Mostly, to have an app-like experience, we include a topbar and a bottom bar, to do that we need to have some elements position: relative to make sure a topbar and bottom bar are 'sticky', the content within it needs to be scrollable.
We are creating an app that should be filled in at a high pace, meaning going through the input fields as quickly as possible. Therefor we want to make sure that the keyboard accessibility bar correctly navigates between the input fields using the previous/next buttons.
That works as expected UNTIL the next input field is outside of content that is visible on iOS. For a long time I thought it had something to do with Cordova, but it has the same problems in Safari. On Android/Chrome it works fine.
In below example, I could go from the first input field to the second input field. But because the last input field was outside of the view, the next button was disabled when the second input field got focus. Thereafter I scrolled downwards and show you that there is a next input field.
So basically, every time you focus an input field the keyboard decides if there is an input field in its current view and based on that enables/disables the prev/next buttons. Important to note is that it does not re-check it: If you decide to use scrolling into view methods on-focus, it does not solve the issue, the button will still be disabled.
Somehow couldn't upload a gif, sorry.

I've narrowed it down to the main source of the problem: overflow: hidden. Here is an over simplified version of the app. Note that a large number of components (in Angular) exist for a lot of re-usability (about 50+ apps depend on this fundament).

<div class="application-wrapper">
  <div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="page-container">
      <div class="page-header">
        THIS IS APP HEADER
      </div>
      <div class="page-content">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
        
              <p>Input field</p>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="insert text here" />
              <br/>
              <p>Input field</p>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="insert text here" />
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <p>Input field</p>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="insert text here" />
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <p>Input field</p>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="insert text here" />
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <p>Input field</p>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="insert text here" />
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <p>Input field</p>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="insert text here" />
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <p>Input field</p>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="insert text here" />
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <p>Input field</p>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="insert text here" />
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <p>Input field</p>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="insert text here" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        
      </div>
      
      </div>
      
    <router-outlet />
  </div>
  <div class="app-bottombar">
    <p>THIS IS THE BOTTOM BAR</p>
  </div>
</div>

.application-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100vw;
    // use viewport height calculated in javascript instead of 100vh which does not work properly in mobile browsers where the address header scrolls away
    height: var(--viewport-height);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    .page-wrapper{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        height: var(--viewport-height);
        overflow: hidden; // removing this 'solves' it, but then the bottom bar is not sticky to the bottom

        .page-container{
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-grow: 1;
            height: 100%;

            .page-header{
                height: 50px;
                color:white;
                background-color: blue;
            }
            .page-content{
                overflow: auto;
            }
        }
    }
    .app-bottombar{
        position: relative;
        height: 75px;
        background-color: red;
        width: 100%;

    }
}


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  title = 'supercoolapp';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // use viewport height calculated in javascript instead of 100vh which does not work properly in mobile browsers where the address header scrolls away
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--viewport-height', `${window.innerHeight}px`);
  }
}


Above code results in:

As you can see, setting the viewport-height manually based on the device height, but as described this solves some other issues regarding the address bar on safari not causing a re-render when it disappears.
